# delete unused images in summernote when updating and delete

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

```
use App\Models\English;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use App\Http\Requests\StoreEnglishRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateEnglishRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Path\To\DOMDocument;
use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;

public function update(Request $request, English $english)
    {
        $rules=[
            'title' => ['required'],
            'slug' => ['required',],
            'content' => ['required']
        ];

        $this->validate($request,$rules);

        $storage="storage/content";
        $dom=new \DOMDocument();
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $dom->loadHTML($request->content,LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);
        libxml_clear_errors();
        $images=$dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
        foreach($images as $img){
            $src=$img->getAttribute('src');
            if(preg_match('/data:image/',$src)){
                preg_match('/data:image\/(?<mime>.*?)\;/',$src,$groups);
                $mimetype=$groups['mime'];
                $fileNameContent = uniqid();
                $fileNameContentRand=substr(md5($fileNameContent),6,6).'_'.time();
                $filepath=("$storage/$fileNameContentRand.$mimetype");
                $image = Image::make($src)
                ->encode($mimetype,100)
                ->save(public_path($filepath));
                $new_src=asset($filepath);
                $img->removeAttribute('src');
                $img->setAttribute('src',$new_src);
                $img->setAttribute('class','img-responsive');
        }

    }


    English::where('id',$english->id)->update([
        'title' => $request->title,
        'name' => auth()->user()->name,
        'slug' => $request->slug,
        'content' => $dom->saveHTML()

    ]);

    return
    redirect('/admin/english');
    }
```

I want to delete my image file data that is in public/storage/content when I change the image during update or it will disappear when I delete it. but I don't have enough knowledge about it to help me solve this problem. this is my code. This update code is almost the same as my store code

I want to be able to delete image files in the public/storage/content directory so that when updates and deletes occur, my program doesn't save too many images.